# How to calculate all possible combinations of brackets order

Tags: math, combinations, computer-science, combinatorics, calculation

I would like to find out a formula on calculating the maximum possible combinations of brackets order.

**First of all there a few rules:**
- Brackets have to be valid (Every bracket has a closing bracket)
- n % 2 == 0 (n = Brackets, only pairs)
- The order is sensitive, e.g.: a,b and b,a equals 2 combinations

**What is a valid combination ?**
Lets say n is our variable for the brackets count:

n = 2:
() - Only 1 combination possible

n = 4
() (), (()) - Only 2 combinations possible

n = 6
((())), () () (), (()()), (())(), ()(()) - 5 possible combinations

**Now any ideas how to calculate the combinations number when I only have n = ?**

*Greetings*

Comment: Might be more suitable on the Math SE.

Comment: (1) Look at how to create the next item in the sequence, given one item. For example, how to get from the first to the second? from the second to the third? third to fourth? Maybe you'll see a pattern there. (2) If you have several numbers in the sequence and don't see a pattern, you can explore the OEIS (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences) to see if it is known in some context. Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate number of valid combinations using table approach.

One dimension of table refers to overall number of brackets in sequence, second dimension refers to number of left brackets, so table cell might be denoted as `F(a, l)`.

You can add right bracket to sequence if `2 * l > a`

You can add left bracket to sequence if `2 * l < n`

So fill table cell by cell and get result as `F(n, n/2)`

There is known formula (Catalan) for number of valid bracket sequences but I suppose that you have to calculate it with simple math logic.